# Fail to get heatmap from MULTIPOINT column of Spatialite layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatialite, heat-map

I got a heatmap from a POINT column of spatialite layer. But, when I made another heatmap from MULTIPOINT column, it was blank. What is the possible reason of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just go to `Vector > Geometry Tools > Multipart to singleparts` to obtain a POINT layer. After that you should be able to obtain the expected heatmap from the newly created point layer.

It seems the Heatmap plugin in QGIS require a `point layer` to create a heatmap from. Maybe in a later version, the plugin will have the ability to work with multipoints.

Comment: Yeah it worked by your tips using geom tools. I got my expected heatmap just now. Thx so much @Sorin.